# Java BASE64 utf8 string decoding

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, base64

I'm using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 do decode string which is utf8. Sometimes I get base64 encoded string which after decode looks like for example `^@kďż˝ďż˝@@`. How can I check if base64 is correct or if decoded utf8 string is valid utf8 string?

To clarify. I'm using

```
public static String base64Decode(String str) {
    try {
        return new String(base64Decode(str.getBytes(Constants.UTF_8)), Constants.UTF_8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         ...
    }
}

public static byte[] base64Decode(byte[] byteArray) {
    return Base64.decodeBase64(byteArray);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean be a String is "UTF-8"? A String object doesn't know about encodings and charsets.

Comment: @Michael Konietzka: I think that is unnecessary nitpicking.  Base64 encodes a sequence of bytes.  I think the OP is clearly saying that the byte sequence is assumed to be the UTF-8 encoding of a unicode string **not** that a `java.lang.String` is directly encoded as Base64 (which as you say would not make sense.)

Comment: @finnw sorry I dont know how to explain clearly. I get encoded string using base64 and I want to check if it is correct. I want to catch situation when I get base64 encoded string which after decoding looks like trash, because everything I received should be some for example name.

Comment: Maybe I just have to check is base64 dont contain any space and other dont allowed chars?

Answer (score 30):

You should specify the charset during converting `String` to `byte[]` and vice versa.

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
// feed bytes to Base64
```

and

```
// get bytes from Base64
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Otherwise the platform default encoding will be used which is not necessarily UTF-8 per se.

Comment: That string does not look like UTF8 misinterpreted as a single-byte encoding.  Could it be GB18030 misinterpreted as UTF8?

Comment: @finnw: The answer indeed assumes that the original string ***is*** UTF-8, as explicitly mentioned by the OP. If this is actually not the case, then the problem is to be solved somewhere else.

Comment: @BalusC: What do you mean by `a String is UTF8`? UTF-8 is an encoding.

Comment: @Michael: the string must have been constructed somehow. For example, if you create the string based on data returned by a `Reader`, you need to ensure as well that the `Reader` is reading the source using UTF-8. I however understand your nitpick, I should probably have worded my previous comment better, e.g. "source" instead of "string".

Comment: i.e `"国家标准"` is neither UTF-8 nor GB18030, it is just a String object. But it can be encoded with UTF-8, GB18030, because these encodings can encode all unicode code points. Of course, the decoding system must use the same character encoding on the bytes as the encoding system. Yes, I am nit-pick on this issue, because in the question "a string is utf-8" was mentioned, which needs clarification, because there is no such thing as a "UTF-8 String". You can encode a String into a byte array using UTF-8, but then there is just a `byte[]`.

Comment: @Michael (and the OP): To the point, when converting `String` to/from `byte[]` you need to specify the *same* character encoding. This is also where my answer is all about. If that doesn't solve the problem, then the original source wasn't in the same encoding at all or the display console (there where you're printing/displaying those chars) doesn't use the same encoding at all. The problem is at least not in Base64 since the character encoding is irrelevant to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var B64 = {
    alphabet: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=',
    lookup: null,
    ie: /MSIE /.test(navigator.userAgent),
    ieo: /MSIE [67]/.test(navigator.userAgent),
    encode: function (s) {
        var buffer = B64.toUtf8(s),
            position = -1,
            len = buffer.length,
            nan1, nan2, enc = [, , , ];
        if (B64.ie) {
            var result = [];
            while (++position < len) {
                nan1 = buffer[position + 1], nan2 = buffer[position + 2];
                enc[0] = buffer[position] >> 2;
                enc[1] = ((buffer[position] & 3) << 4) | (buffer[++position] >> 4);
                if (isNaN(nan1)) enc[2] = enc[3] = 64;
                else {
                    enc[2] = ((buffer[position] & 15) << 2) | (buffer[++position] >> 6);
                    enc[3] = (isNaN(nan2)) ? 64 : buffer[position] & 63;
                }
                result.push(B64.alphabet[enc[0]], B64.alphabet[enc[1]], B64.alphabet[enc[2]], B64.alphabet[enc[3]]);
            }
            return result.join('');
        } else {
            result = '';
            while (++position < len) {
                nan1 = buffer[position + 1], nan2 = buffer[position + 2];
                enc[0] = buffer[position] >> 2;
                enc[1] = ((buffer[position] & 3) << 4) | (buffer[++position] >> 4);
                if (isNaN(nan1)) enc[2] = enc[3] = 64;
                else {
                    enc[2] = ((buffer[position] & 15) << 2) | (buffer[++position] >> 6);
                    enc[3] = (isNaN(nan2)) ? 64 : buffer[position] & 63;
                }
                result += B64.alphabet[enc[0]] + B64.alphabet[enc[1]] + B64.alphabet[enc[2]] + B64.alphabet[enc[3]];
            }
            return result;
        }
    },
    decode: function (s) {
        var buffer = B64.fromUtf8(s),
            position = 0,
            len = buffer.length;
        if (B64.ieo) {
            result = [];
            while (position < len) {
                if (buffer[position] < 128) result.push(String.fromCharCode(buffer[position++]));
                else if (buffer[position] > 191 && buffer[position] < 224) result.push(String.fromCharCode(((buffer[position++] & 31) << 6) | (buffer[position++] & 63)));
                else result.push(String.fromCharCode(((buffer[position++] & 15) << 12) | ((buffer[position++] & 63) << 6) | (buffer[position++] & 63)));
            }
            return result.join('');
        } else {
            result = '';
            while (position < len) {
                if (buffer[position] < 128) result += String.fromCharCode(buffer[position++]);
                else if (buffer[position] > 191 && buffer[position] < 224) result += String.fromCharCode(((buffer[position++] & 31) << 6) | (buffer[position++] & 63));
                else result += String.fromCharCode(((buffer[position++] & 15) << 12) | ((buffer[position++] & 63) << 6) | (buffer[position++] & 63));
            }
            return result;
        }
    },
    toUtf8: function (s) {
        var position = -1,
            len = s.length,
            chr, buffer = [];
        if (/^[\x00-\x7f]*$/.test(s)) while (++position < len)
        buffer.push(s.charCodeAt(position));
        else while (++position < len) {
            chr = s.charCodeAt(position);
            if (chr < 128) buffer.push(chr);
            else if (chr < 2048) buffer.push((chr >> 6) | 192, (chr & 63) | 128);
            else buffer.push((chr >> 12) | 224, ((chr >> 6) & 63) | 128, (chr & 63) | 128);
        }
        return buffer;
    },
    fromUtf8: function (s) {
        var position = -1,
            len, buffer = [],
            enc = [, , , ];
        if (!B64.lookup) {
            len = B64.alphabet.length;
            B64.lookup = {};
            while (++position < len)
            B64.lookup[B64.alphabet[position]] = position;
            position = -1;
        }
        len = s.length;
        while (position < len) {
            enc[0] = B64.lookup[s.charAt(++position)];
            enc[1] = B64.lookup[s.charAt(++position)];
            buffer.push((enc[0] << 2) | (enc[1] >> 4));
            enc[2] = B64.lookup[s.charAt(++position)];
            if (enc[2] == 64) break;
            buffer.push(((enc[1] & 15) << 4) | (enc[2] >> 2));
            enc[3] = B64.lookup[s.charAt(++position)];
            if (enc[3] == 64) break;
            buffer.push(((enc[2] & 3) << 6) | enc[3]);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
};
```

View [Here](http://jsbase64.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This one worked perfectly for me. I understand it got a negative vote because its a javascript answer on a java question.

Answer (score 0):

I created this method:

```
public static String descodificarDeBase64(String stringCondificado){
    try {
        return new String(Base64.decode(stringCondificado.getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

So I can decode from Base64 spanish characthers as á,ñ,í,ü.

Example:

```
descodificarDeBase64("wr9xdcOpIHRhbD8=");
```

will return: ¿Qué tal?

Comment: Base64.DEFAULT is undefined