# Google Cloud Dataflow removing accents and special chars with '??'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

This is going to be quite a hit or miss question as I don't really know which context or piece of code to give you as it is a situation of `it works in local`, which does!

The situation here is that I have several services, and there's a step where messages are put in a PubSub topic awaiting for the Dataflow consumer to handle them and save as .parquet files (I also have another one which sends that payload to a HTTP endpoint).

The thing is, the message in that service prior sending it to that PubSub topic seems to be correct, Stackdriver logs show all the chars as they should be.

However, when I'm going to check the final output in .parquet or in the HTTP endpoint I just see, for example `h??` instead of `hí`, which seems pretty weird as running everything in local makes the output be correct.

I can only think about encoding server-wise when deploying the Dataflow as a job and not running in local.

Hope someone can shed some light in something this abstract.

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: @Pablo we're using Beam 2.9.0, updating to newer ones would constantly throw errors in Stackdriver saying something related to resources and that they couldn't be correctly allocated.

Comment: Are you using also the Java SDK?

Comment: @Pablo yes I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strange thing is that it works locally.
But as a workaround, the first thing that comes to mind is to use encoding.

Are you using at some point a function to convert your string input as bytes?
If yes, you could try to force getBytes() to use utf-8 encoding by passing by the argument like in the following example from this Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714584/11928117):

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
// feed bytes to Base64
```

```
// get bytes from Base64
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Also:
- Have you tried setting the parquet.enable.dictionary option?
- Are your original files written in utf-8 before conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Dataflow (at least the Java SDK) replaces Spanish characters like 'ñ' or accents 'á','é',' etc with the symbol � since the default charset of the JVM installed on service workers is US-ASCII. So, if UTF-8 is not explicitly declared when you instantiate strings or their relative byte-arrays transformation, the platform default encoding will be used.